# Flurry linker Error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, flurry

Every time I open my same project first time in Xcode it gives me an linker error,please see below screen shot.

I always resolve this error by just removing reference of flurry folder and again drag into my project folder directory, but next day it again gives me the same error.

But till yet i did not get its permanent solution.
Anybody please suggest that how i can fix this issue permanently.

[image]